# Updating cell color based off of multiple other cell colors

Tags: excel, vba

Code Edited based on comments:

I am definitely not an excel VBA expert, I usually find answers to my questions online, but this one is eluding me.  I have a spreadsheet where I wish to change a cell color if and only if 3 other cells have their color changed too.  Specifically one cell up and left from the first checked cell.  Example A1 changes if B2, B3, and B4 are changed.

I have found created a subroutine that should do what I am asking, but it does not.  Can you help?

**First a subroutine to execute the function I operation**

```
    Sub checkcolor(cellx As Range, celly As Range, cellz As Range)
    
    If cellx.Interior.Color = celly.Interior.Color And celly.Interior.Color = cellz.Interior.Color Then cellx.offset(-1, -1).Interior.Color = cellx.Interior.Color
End Sub
```

**Then a call button subroutine so I can execute with specific cells**

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Call checkcolor(Range("B2"), Range("B3"), Range("B4"))
End Sub
```

What am I missing to make this work?  I am getting an argument error on the button click.  Please help, Thanks
Steve

Comment: `B1, B2, B3` - these are undeclared variables. You want `Range("B1")`, `Range("B2")`, `Range("B3")`.

Comment: `Offset(cellx, -1, -1)` ---> `cellx.Offset(-1, -1)`.

Comment: BigBen,  Thank you for your feedback. I updated the Code to the following:  Sub checkcolor(cellx As Range, celly As Range, cellz As Range)

If cellx.Interior.Color = celly.Interior.Color And celly.Interior.Color = cellz.Interior.Color Then cellx.Offset(-1, -1).Interior.Color = cellx.Interior.Color
End If
End Sub               I get a "End If without Block If" Error.  If I delete the 'EndIf' then I get a "Run Time 1004 Error, Application defined or Object Defined error" with the debugger highlighting "cellx.Offset(-1, -1).Interior.Color = cellx.Interior.Color" section of code

Comment: I didnt see a way to add carriage returns or Code Snippets to the Reply :(

Comment: The comment space isn't really meant for code, best to [edit] your question, but your problem is that `cellx` is `Range("B1")` so you can't offset up one row. Your code would be more robust if you checked `If cellx.Row > 1 And cellX.Column > 1` before attempting `.Offset(-1, -1)`

Comment: Ben, again thank you for the feedback.  This last update does not help me unfortunately, as I am not sure what you are asking.  Since I am inputting the specific cells I am calling into the button subroutine, in this case B1, B2, B3, I know that these are more than 1 and 1.  I would be specifying this for about a dozen such commands where the row and column is always greater than 1.  Why is what you are saying needed, and how do I implement it in the code above?

Comment: You're attempting to call `.Offset(-1, -1)` on a cell in row 1 (cell B1). That's impossible, because there is no row 0. Did you mean to use cell B2 as the first argument?

Comment: Yes you are right, This whole time I was mis mentioning the cells, I was trying to compare B2, B3, and B4.  When I entered the correct cells into the formula, it works.  Thank you for the help, I was really running into a wall on this one.